# Python 3.6 tuple to string

Tags: string, python-3.x, tuples

```
print(c_tuple)

print(type(c_tuple))


# returns the following
((82,),)
<class 'tuple'>
```

is there anyway that we can convert ((82,),) into a 82 string ?  I have tried multiple ways and none of them works in Python 3.6

```
c_tuple = ''.join(c_tuple) # returns "TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, tuple found"

c_tuple = str(c_tuple) # still returns ((82,),)
```

Could any guru enlighten?

Comment: `''.join(map(str, c_tuple))` would be one way, `str(c_tuple[0])` another

Comment: Hi both of them ''".join(map(str, c_tuple)) & str(c_tuple[0])  returns (82,). Any way to get rid of (,) and leave it as 82?

Comment: You have a nested tuple, index until you get what you need: `str(c_tuple[0][0])`.

Comment: Yes this nested tuple is the answer! str(c_tuple[0][0]) returns the correct format! Would you like to create an answer and I will vote for it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method below

```
tuple = (1,(82,123,), "asd",)


    def tupleTostr(tuple):
        res = ""
        for a in tuple:
            if type(a) is type(tuple):
                res += tupleTostr(a)
            else:
                res += str(a)
        return res


    print(tupleTostr(tuple))
```

gives the output 182123asd

Comment: -1 ```>>> ''.__iter__
<method-wrapper '__iter__' of str object at 0x7fcbd43a9ab0>
```